# $l^1(\Bbb{R})$ is not closed in $E=(l^{\infty},\Vert\Vert_{\infty}).$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I have some difficulties to prove that $l^1(\Bbb{R})$ is not closed in $E=(l^{\infty},\Vert\Vert_{\infty}).$

So I need to find a real sequence in $l^1$ which converges in $l^\infty$ buy such that the limit is not is $l^1$,

I tried something like $(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots,1/p,0,\cdots,0)=x^{(p)}$, the serie converges because is being $0$ so it's in $l^1$ right? So now, I need to prove that the sequence converges in $l^\infty$ sense, if I look at $$x=(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots,0,\cdots)$$ then $\Vert x^{p}-x\Vert_{\infty}=\sup_{p\ge 1}(0,0,0,\cdots,1/p,\cdots)=1/p\to0.$

But why $x$ does not belong in $l^1$? Perhaps I misunderstand something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector space $\ell^1$ is defined as the set of sequences $(x_1,x_2, \ldots)$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1} ^\infty |x_i|$ converges.

The vector $\displaystyle x = \Big (1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1}, \ldots \Big)$ is not an element of $\ell^1$ because $\displaystyle \|x\|_1 = \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series $-$ hence divergent.

Comment: But what is the difference between $x$ and $x^{(p})$?

Comment: All the entries in $x$ are nonzero. The entries of $x^{(p)}$ are all zero beyond the $p$th place. If you mean 'difference' as in distance then $\|x-x^{(p)}\|_\infty = 1/p$ but $\|x-x^{(p)}\|_1 = \infty$.

Comment: hm ok, so my $x$ was not correct, I see, thanks.